# Two vectors are in the same direction if?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Are two vectors in the same direction if their dot product is greater than zero/positive? I know they are orthogonal if their dot product is 0 so they can not be in the same direction. I also read if a vector `u` is scalar multiple of `v`, they are in the same direction? I can not find a definitive answer.

Comment: One should be a positive scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: @Randall what about if their dot product is positive? Can we say the two vectors are in the same direction and opposite direction if negative?

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Positive dot product means acute angle, not the same direction necessarily.

Comment: Consider $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ (*i.e. east and northeast*) I would not say are in the same direction, this is despite their dot product $(0,1)\cdot (1,1)=0\cdot1+1\cdot1=1>0$.  All that you can say when the dotproduct is nonzero is that they are not orthogonal.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks that clears a lot of the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two vectors are in *exactly* the same direction if one is a **positive** scalar multiple of the other. Related facts:

- Two vectors form an acute angle if their dot product is positive, and
- two vectors form an obtuse angle if their dot product is negative.

Answer (score 4):

[image: visual]

Two vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ are in the same direction if and only if $$\frac{\mathbf{v}}{v}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{w}}{w}=1$$

One of the many ways your can rephrase this is $\mathbf{\hat v}=\mathbf{\hat w}$. You are right that they are scalar multiples.

Comment: $v$ and $w$ are lengths of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$, right?

Comment: Being scalar multiples is necessary but not sufficient, since for $v \neq 0, v$ and $-v$ are scalar multiples but not in the same direction.

Answer (score 3):

Vectors u and v are in same direction if their unit norm are equal ie vectors are scalar multiple of each other.
$$\frac{u}{||u||}=\frac{v}{||v||}$$

Comment: I believe this incorrect, since a. they need to be **positive** scalar multiples and b. the zero vector is in the same direction as itself even though it does not have a unit norm